# Substraction by the column just created in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My query is supposedly create new column based on the keyword in data using bigquery. For example if in data consists 'Mike' it will create Mike column, 'John' will create John column and the list goes on..
However, I want to create a 'other' column that is the substraction of overall name with the column I just created.

My code example (wrong at SUBSTRACT function):

```
  SELECT 
   COUNT(Name) as n_name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%MIKE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mike,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%JOHN%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS John,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%MICHAEL%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Michael,
        .....
        SUBSTRACT (n_name ,Mike and John)  AS Others
     FROM t
```

Is there any way to do some substraction by the column I just created ?

Comment: Your logic actually looks correct so far for the other case.  What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I just rephrased my question as my previous post is different from the real question I want to ask.. Please check thanks

Comment: you should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we see input data and expected output. otherwise it is hard to see what exactly you want or what exactly problem you have

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Do you only answer BigQuery questions?

Comment: yes. why you ask? :o)

Comment: I've solved this problem.. Thanks everyone for your time.. @MikhailBerlyant  feel free to delete this post if it is not fulfill the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT *, 
  n_name - Mike - John - Michael AS Other
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(Name) AS n_name,
    COUNTIF(Name LIKE '%MIKE%') AS Mike,
    COUNTIF(Name LIKE '%JOHN%') AS John,
    COUNTIF(Name LIKE '%MICHAEL%') AS Michael,
  FROM t 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
     *
     ,n_name - Mike - John - Michael AS Other
     FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(Name) AS n_name
                ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Name like '%MIKE%' THEN 1 END) AS Mike
                ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%JOHN%' THEN 1 END) AS John
                ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%MICHAEL%' THEN 1 END) AS Michael
            FROM 
                t
        ) aa
```